# How can I parse through a csv file within the DJANGO framework?

Tags: django, csv

I am creating a scientific based website that does some calculation and plots. In order to do those calculations, I need to use some data that is in a csv file. The csv file has around 10,000 columns and 7 rows. Will I be able to do this with DJANGO?

Comment: You don't. You use Python's CSV handling.

Comment: python has a [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module that you can use within Django.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Backend of Django is just python, which means you can use any python packages and what not in your views for example. You can probably start off [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Edit: If you just parse the csv, you can use that data any way you'd like in django, maybe passing to the frontend template, storing it in the database, etc.